# Is there any alternative to DragOver to suppress glyph on drag drop?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have a UWP App (a game). The entire App surface is a Win2D AnimatedCanvasControl with Drag/Drop enabled.

I have coded a DragOver handler to suppress the framework caption ("Move"/"Copy"/etc.) and glyph.

```
private void CnvGemSmash_DragOver (Object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.AcceptedOperation                 =   DataPackageOperation.None;
    e.DragUIOverride.IsCaptionVisible   =   false;
    e.DragUIOverride.IsGlyphVisible     =   false;
```

This works - BUT not until after about a 1 second delay after the drag starts. I've scoured the APIs looking for a way to avoid the glyph appearing for that fraction of a second - it looks awful in my App.
Is there any way around this?

[image]

Comment: This code [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop) may be helpful.

Comment: Please try modify `e.AcceptedOperation`   to   `DataPackageOperation.Copy`.

Comment: @NicoZhu I've looked at the samples and the API reference. What I'm taking from them is that I cannot suppress the glyph on DragStarting as the version of DragUI which is passed into that event doesn't expose the glyph. So, my first opportunity to remove the glyph is DragOver or DragEnter. Which is what I've done. (Changing the AcceptedOperation would just give me a different glyph - not sure how that would help!?). I maybe understand why there's a brief delay before firing the first DragOver/Enter events, but in light of that, the API seems broken in so far as it won't let me manage glyphs.

Comment: Yep, your are right. the reason is that the item hover area is not support drop when Drag Starting. It is by design.

Comment: @NicoZhu Thank you for the confirmation. I guess I'll do my own Drag/Drop implementation. Please post your response as an answer so I can accept. It's exactly what I asked the question for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I'm taking from them is that I cannot suppress the glyph on DragStarting as the version of DragUI which is passed into that event doesn't expose the glyph.

The reason is that the item hover area is not support drop when Drag Starting. It is by design.